# How to plublic goagent service on local area network

Tags: vpn

Default goagent setting on 127.0.0.1:8087.I want public my goagent proxy service on 192.168.1.101:8080 so that my iphone can also visit facebook.
is there any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to configure the proxy.ini(in folder 'local') as below:

```
[listen]
ip = your-hostname
port = 8087
visible = 1
debuginfo = 0
```

Replace your-hostname with your real hostname.